# Adding File under label header or source Visual Studio add-in

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

With Following code I am able to add new files to visual studio project.

```
 DTE dte = GetService(typeof(DTE)) as DTE;
            System.Array theProjects = (System.Array)dte.ActiveSolutionProjects;
            EnvDTE.Project theProject = null;
            if (theProjects.Length > 0)
            {
                theProject = (EnvDTE.Project)(theProjects.GetValue(0));
                EnvDTE.ProjectItem projItem = null;
                projItem  = theProject.ProjectItems.AddFromFile(@"E:\Avinash\test.cpp");
            }
```

But if i have to add a `header file`, how do i add it under `header` label.

Answer (score 1):

If I correctly understand what you are trying to do, I think you mean that you want to add your header files in the header folder. If it's already there you have to look for it among the items for your project. I.e. you have to loop looking for the ProjectItem with the name you are looking for. If it's not already there, you can add it using the AddFolder of ProjectItemsCollection, which returns the newly created ProjectItem. In either case you end up with a ProjectItem representing the headers folder. Now you can add your file to the ProjectItems of this object instead of the ProjectItems of the Project. Something like this:

```
theProject = (EnvDTE.Project)(theProjects.GetValue(0));
EnvDTE.ProjectItem projItem = null;
EnvDTE.ProjectItem hdrProjItem = theProject.ProjectItems.AddFolder("Header files", null);
projItem  = hdrProjItem.ProjectItems.AddFromFile(@"E:\Avinash\test.cpp");
```

Anyway, I still think a template could avoid you much effort and pain